# Properties in interfaces c#

Tags: c#

How you can have properties in an interface if an interface isn't supposed to have attributes in C#,as properties are getters and setters for attributes? At the class we had this example and i thought an interface should only have method declarations.

```
interface IKnownProgrammingLanguages
{
    string[] ProgrammingLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: "an interface isn't supposed to have attributes in C#" - what do you mean by "attributes"? Why not? Interfaces obviously *can* have properties.

Comment: Interfaces aren't supposed to offer any _implementation_. The allowed syntax for properties doesn't allow for implementation, so everything is fine. A property is just shorthand for a get and/or set method.

Comment: Properties are methods.

Comment: Sounds merely like a terminology confusion.  You declared the *accessors* for the property, promising that it will have both a getter and a setter accessor.  C# syntax for properties is not fantastic, it got muddled by the syntax for auto-implemented properties in C# version 3.  Which looks like that as well, does something very different when it appears inside a class instead of an interface.  They couldn't think of a better way to declare them, I can't either :)

Comment: @IllidanS4, properties are NOT methods. You do not invoke like a method

Comment: Property accessors are methods.  More confusion.

Comment: @Renato Afonso: Actually property (getters and setters) are invoked exactly like methods if you look at the IL code.

Comment: Under the hood, it is just `get_ProgrammingLanguages` and `set_ProgrammingLanguages`. Sometimes it is helpful to think about it like that, sometimes it's not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties are just a nicely looking function declarations. Beneath the sugar, they look something like this:

```
interface IKnownProgrammingLanguages
{
    void SetProgrammingLanguages(string[] value);
    string[] GetProgrammingLanguages();
}
```

Interfaces aren't supposed to have attributes because implementing classes can't change the behavior of the attributes - they always work the same way. But each implementing class can define how the `SetProgrammingLanguages` and `GetProgrammingLanguages` operate, that's why they are allowed, and often useful.

Answer (score 1):

Interface as defined should have only signature and declaration should be in the class in which the interface is inherited this is same for methods and properties

Eg:

```
public interface ISchool {

    string[] ParentNumber
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public class School : ISchool
{
    string[] parentNumber;
    public string [] ParentNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parentNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value[0] == "MS")
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            else
                this.parentNumber = value;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISchool tt = new School();

        tt.ParentNumber = new string [] {"MSX", "TY", "KU"};

        foreach (var pst in tt.ParentNumber)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pst);
        }


        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An interface declares what to be expected. Properties can be included in an interface. It is up to the implementation to comply with the interface.

The following interface

```cs
interface IKnownProgrammingLanguages
{
    string[] ProgrammingLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

Can be implemented by a class like this

```cs
class KnownProgrammingLanguages : IKnownProgrammingLanguages
{
    public string[] ProgrammingLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

If an interface defines a Getter proprty only as in:

```cs
interface IKnownProgrammingLanguagesGetterOnly
{
    string[] ProgrammingLanguages { get; }
}
```

The implementation must have a Getter but also implements a Setter if needed. As long as it complies with the interface.

```cs
class KnownProgrammingLanguages : IKnownProgrammingLanguagesGetterOnly
{
    public string[] ProgrammingLanguages { get; set; }
}
```

It is to be noted, the implementation can implement multiple interfaces as well and have its own method and properties on top of it.

```cs
interface IFoo
{
    string Foo { get; }
}

interface IBar
{
    void Bar();
}

class BarAndFoo: IFoo, IBar
{
   public int OtherProperty { get; set; } // not defined in any interface

    public string Foo { get; set; } // complies with IFoo

    public void Bar() // complies with IBar
    {

    }
}
```